# dotnet run watch : Exited with error code 1

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using an Angular C# app with asp.net-core-2.0. I added the dotnet watch library so when i make changes to my C# controller, my Angular app will be updated as well.

I included this line in my `.csproj` file

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When i make change to my C# controller, i get this error : `watch : Exited with error code 1` and my angular app is not updating since i need to refresh the browser manually to see the changes. Any idea why i have this error and how i can resolve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but i was facing the same problem, and i saw [here](http://%00https://github.com/SAFE-Stack/SAFE-template/issues/12) that this is the normal behavior.

In the case of angular is normal that you have to refresh the browser because the dotnet watcher restart the app and the web server on every change that you do on any cs file.

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/blob/dev/src/dotnet-watch/README.md) you can find more detail about it and the source code if you want to know what happening under the hood.